# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError : Can't connect to mysql in docker

Tags: python, mysql, docker, sqlalchemy, docker-compose

I am working with sqlalchemy and mysql, the process is working fine for mysql installed locally but I am not able to connect it with a mysql docker image. I am using pymysql as a driver. Here is the line of commands that I run and I am getting an error shown below.

Following are the portions of /docker-compose.yml and the python file. Also I have a script that creates a database named "sqlalchemy" in docker mysql which is not shown below.

/docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  db:
    build: ./database
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3309:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
```

/sqlalchemy.py

```
 msqldb_uri = 'mysql+pymysql://root:password@db:3309/sqlalchemy'
 engine = create_engine(msqldb_uri)



sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
```

Answer (score 2):

If the script is running inside container then you do not use the publish port in the connection but you should use `3306` within localhost or same network. The publish port is for outer world.

```
 msqldb_uri = 'mysql+pymysql://root:password@localhost:3306/sqlalchemy'
 engine = create_engine(msqldb_uri)
```

If the script is runnin in other container that is in the same docker-compose file then you also you do not need the publish port.

```
 msqldb_uri = 'mysql+pymysql://root:password@db:3306/sqlalchemy'
 engine = create_engine(msqldb_uri)
```

if the script in running on host and DB is running inside container then you need  connect with the publish port but you should not use container name as a IP.

```
 msqldb_uri = 'mysql+pymysql://root:password@localhost:3309/sqlalchemy'
 engine = create_engine(msqldb_uri)
```

Comment: is the complete dockercompose file if not post the whole? they will only communicate with name if in the same network.